# useState method not updating state with onClick?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am creating a custom multiple choice question, but I am having difficulties updating my selection choice using useState.

```
const QuestionPage = ({ audioFiles }) => {
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState(-1); // -1 is when none of the choices are selected
  
  const updateChoice = val => {
    setChoice(val);
  }

  return (
    // each MultipleChoice contains an audio file and a radio button
    <MultipleChoice audioFiles={audioFiles} choice={choice} updateChoice={updateChoice} />
  )
};
```

```
const MultipleChoice = ({ audioFiles, choice, updateChoice }) => {
  const answerOption = audioFiles.map((item, key) =>
    <AudioButton file={file} index={key} choice={choice} updateChoice={updateChoice} />
  );
  return (
    {answerOption}
  );
}
```

```
const AudioButton = ({ file, index, choice, updateChoice }) => {
  const handleClick = (val) => {
    updateChoice(val);
  };

  const radioButton = (
    <div className={`${index === choice ? "selected" : ""}`} onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <>
      {radioButton}
      <Audio file={file} />
    </> 
  );
}
```

In the first function, `QuestionPage` within `updateChoice`, when I use `console.log(val)`, it updates according to the selections I make (i.e. 0 and 1). However, when I call `console.log(choice)`, it keeps printing `-1`.

In addition, I keep getting an error message that says `updateChoice` is not a function.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did not pass the value of `audioFiles` in `MultipleChoice` function

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it in my post. But I do have it in my actual code, so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: so you should post a sample of `audioFiles` here for investigation